# How do I figure out the setup of composition api?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

What does setup function's `return` value do?

```
const Comp = defineComponent({
    props: {
        count: {
          default: 0
        }
    },
    setup(props) {
        return () => props.count;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently v2 of Vue.js uses the Option Based API - using `data`, `methods` and `computed` options. While this API works great for building components, in reality, it ends up fragmenting the **Business logic** into various code blocks. Further, you cannot simply reuse some options of one component into another component. For example, say you have bunch of methods that you need to be shared with other component which can work with only inheritance or mixins which are not simple and intuitive to use.

Composition API i.e. using new lifecycle method `setup` exactly solves the problem. It helps you define components reactive properties, methods and computed properties using those reactive properties within a single ordinary JavaScript function without any magic. The `this` pointer is not used within the `setup` method. And, thus the `setup` function can be extracted outside of the component and reused in various components.

```
<template>
  <button @click="increment">
    Count is: {{ count }}, double is {{ double }}, click to increment.
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed, onMounted } from 'vue'

function useCounter() {

  // 1. Reactive property
  // Similar to one returned from `data` function
  const count = ref(0);

  // 2. Computed property
  const double = computed(() => count.value * 2);

  // 3. Methods
  function increment() {
    count.value++;
  }

  // 4. Lifecycle methods
  onMounted(() => console.log('component mounted!'));

  // Return the context object containing all/some 
  // of the 4 types of values
  return {
    count,
    double,
    increment
  };
}

export default {
  setup() {

    const reactiveContext = useCounter();

    return reactiveContext;
  }
}
</script>
```

Check the `useCounter` function. It is outside of the component and used as part of counter component using the `setup` method. All the props returned by `setup` are accessible on component instance and can be used directly inside the template.

Use this link - https://composition-api.vuejs.org/ to learn more about the composition API.

Comment: thank you very much, i still want to ask. because i don't konw the return in my code pieces which is the impact?  the sources code is in the GitHub\vue-next\packages\runtime-core\__tests__\apiCreateApp.spec.ts

Comment: @joan, the setup method should return an object containing all your component props and methods that will be available to the template during rendering.